# Fundamental group under Gelfand duality

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, fundamental-group, gelfand-duality

Gelfand duality states that the functor of continuous functions $C(-)$ from compact Hausdorff topological to commutative $C^*$-algebras is an equivalence of categories. In other words, all topological properties of such a topological space $X$ are encoded in the algebraic properties (and of course the norm) of $C(X)$.

I have the following related questions:

1. How does one recognize that $X$ is simply connected from the algebraic properties of $C(X)$?
2. How can the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ be defined in terms of the algebraic properties of $C(X)$?
3. If $\tilde{X}$ is a universal cover of $X$, what is the algebraic relation between $C(\tilde{X})$ and $C(X)$?

Comment: The universal cover of a compact space will only be locally compact so you will need to use that form of duality.

Comment: I'll add that compact Hausdorff spaces are under no obligation whatsoever to admit a universal cover. For example, in $(S^1)^{\mathbb{N}}$ each open set contains a non-contractible loop, so a covering space of it cannot be simply connected.

Comment: If the space is simply connected then every line bundle over it is trivial and line bundles correspond to rank 1 projections in $M_\infty(C(X))$ (so all rank 1 projections are conjugate/homotopic/Murray-von Neumann equivalent). Not sure whether the converse is true.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Clearly, the parameters of the question should be tweaked to get a reasonable answer. But since I don't know what the answer should look like, it's hard to predict how to best modify the question. It's reasonable to expect, should a construction of the fundamental group or universal cover exist at the algebra level, that it would work when it can work and fail when it can't. And I'd be quite happy with that!

Comment: I guess you could take the definition of fundamental group and apply duality to each step. For example a loop would be a morphism to the algebra of continuous functions on the circle, a homotopy between loops would be a morphism to the algebra of continuous functions on a cylinder, etc... not sure how simple the end result would be though

Comment: @PetrNaryshkin No, all line bundles are trivial iff $\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1X,\mathbb{Z}/2)=0$ (indeed, that hom is equivalent to the Picard group of real line bundles). If you meant line bundles in the complex sense, then it is not true that on a simply connected space all line bundles are trivial: indeed $\mathbb{CP}^\infty$ carries the universal line bundle and it is simply connected (if you want to restrict to compact Hausdorff spaces, just take $\mathbb{CP}^n$ for any $n>0$)

Comment: Also, another observation is that for general compact Hausdorff spaces "having trivial $\pi_1(X)$" and "having no nontrivial covering spaces" are different conditions, and I would argue that the "correct" generalization of simply connected is the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this question has been investigated in the literature, where the fundamental group is approached through the notion of a regular covering. For instance, the following reference establishes an equivalence between the categories of regular coverings $\tilde{X} \to X$ and Galois extensions of $C(X)$, meaning that the algebraic analog of a universal cover is a universal Galois extension and the fundamental group is the group associated to that extension:

> *Høst-Madsen, Anders*, [**Separable algebras and covering spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-14306), Math. Scand. 87, No. 2, 211-239 (2000). [ZBL1002.54010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1002.54010). [MR1795745](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1795745).

More literature on this topic is cited therein.

Answer (score 2):

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopical+structure+on+C%2A-algebras

might be a useful pointer. It gives basic definitions for doing homotopy at the $C^*$-algebra level.